# Python requests wait for redirect

Tags: python, python-requests, bots

I'm trying to access a website that verifies I'm not a bot by redirecting after a few seconds. How do I have the requests module wait for a redirect?

Edit: It seems I didn't entirely understand the problem. I liked Kirk Strauser's response, but couldn't find a location header.

I found out that the site was managed with Cloudflare. I tried using cfscrape, which didn't work, and cloudscraper hasn't updated for this captcha version yet. Probably not going to be solved on stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

The `requests` module has a parameter for configuring `allow_redirects` if you need to follow the redirected 300-series response.

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://github.com/', allow_redirects=False)

>>> r.status_code
301

>>> r.history
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

In that specific case, you can sleep a little while and then manually visit the next location:

```
import time

import requests

r = requests.get('http://github.com/', allow_redirects=False)

# Don't fetch the next page too quickly
time.sleep(3)

# Now go to the URL that the previous request would have gone to
# if you hadn't asked requests.get not to.
r = requests.get(r.headers['Location'])
```

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative could be using some automation framework such as Selenium or playwright (at the cost of a slower execution).

### Playwright implementation:

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import time

async def getDelayedContent(url):
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        return await page.content()

print(asyncio.run(getDelayedContent("https://stackoverflow.com/")))
```

If you opt for this alternative don't forget to import asyncio, and run your async function with it.